# Custom Navigation Bar breaks apart in Chrome.

Tags: css, google-chrome

I am just cleaning up some CSS for a client.

I am not a front-end person, but have been saved by bootstrap (thank you, twitter).

However, I am having a really hard time cleaning up a custom navigation panel
(no twitter). I have provided the CSS below. I need it to be able to:

1) close gracefully at the end (the beginning starts with a vertical border, not an arrow.
I would like the end to have symmetry and close the way it began).

2) Get the container to not expand to the end of the page.

3) I can't seem to get it to work in chrome. It falls apart in chrome but works in IE and Ff.

Here is the link. Any advice? Thanks so much.

http://annualdinnerdev.elasticbeanstalk.com/

```
 /* ------- Wizard Interface ---------- */

 #wizHeader
        {
            border: solid 3px #fff;
            margin-bottom:25px;
            -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #C2CBCE;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #C2CBCE;
            box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #C2CBCE; /* For IE 8 */
            -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#C2CBCE')"; /* For IE 5.5 - 7 */
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color= '#C2CBCE' );

        }

        #wizHeader li label
        {
            font-size:x-large;
        }

        #wizHeader li a
        {
            font-size:large;
        }

        #wizHeader li .prevStep
        {
            background-color: #D6E6FA;
            color:#000;
        }
        #wizHeader li .prevStep:after
        {
            border-left-color: #D6E6FA !important;
        }
        #wizHeader li .currentStep
        {
            background-color: #6699CC;
            color:#fff;
        }
        #wizHeader li .currentStep:after
        {
            border-left-color: #6699CC !important;
        }
        #wizHeader li .nextStep
        {
            background-color: #F0E9EA;
            color:gray;
        }
        #wizHeader li .nextStep:after
        {
            border-left-color: #F0E9EA !important;
        }
        #wizHeader
        {
            list-style: none;
            overflow: hidden;
            font: 14px Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }
        #wizHeader li
        {
            float: left;
        }
        #wizHeader li a
        {
            color: white;
            text-decoration: none;
            padding: 10px 0 10px 55px;
            background: brown; /* fallback color */
            background: hsla(34,85%,35%,1);
            position: relative;
            display: block;
            float: left;
        }
        #wizHeader li a:after
        {
            content: " ";
            display: block;
            width: 0;
            height: 0;
            border-top: 50px solid transparent; /* Go big on the size, and let overflow hide */
            border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
            border-left: 30px solid hsla(34,85%,35%,1);
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            margin-top: -50px;
            left: 100%;
            z-index: 2;
        }
        #wizHeader li a:before
        {
            content: " ";
            display: block;
            width: 0;
            height: 0;
            border-top: 50px solid transparent;
            border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
            border-left: 35px solid white;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            margin-top: -50px;
            margin-left: 1px;
            left: 100%;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        #wizHeader li:first-child a
        {
            padding-left: 10px;
        }
        #wizHeader li:last-child
        {
            padding-right: 18px;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a background color to #wizHeader to create the visual of a right-side border.
2. Specify a width value in #wizHeader to prevent it from expanding to the right of the page.
3. It seems to be working fine on Chrome for me (latest version)

Here are some examples of declarations to add to #wizHeader (add these to the ones currently in the CSS declaration)

```
 #wizHeader {
   background: #6699CC; 
   width: 960px; 
}
```

**Adding more based on comment...**

The reason the arrows are being bumped down is because the 's are block elements, floated left, so they'll flow to fit whatever width they have available and drop down onto the next line when they run out.

If you want to cut off the last arrow, you'll have better luck by targeting the

that wraps the last . This worked for me, editing in Chrome's Inspector:

```
#wizHeader li:last-child {
  width: 172px; /* you might have to tweak this a bit*/
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

Then, change the width of the #wizHeader accordingly. 930px wide seemed to do the trick with the above snippet.

Comment: Thanks so much. I am trying to extend the arrows beyond the width, and hide the overflow. But when I add "overflow:hidden" to #wizHeader, it still bumps the last arrow down to the next row. It doesn't want to allow overflow. Any idea why this would be?

Comment: That helped immensely, thank you so much. I have it looking reasonably pretty in both IE and Ff. Your tweak did the trick. However, I still can't make the dog hunt in Chrome. It pushes down a level still. It almost looks like the font is larger in Chrome. I have updated the link I posted. Take another look if you don't mind and let me know why you think Chrome is still wonky.

Comment: Different browser engines render fonts differently, so its quite likely the font's larger in Chrome. Try setting an explicit width on the rest of the #wizHeader li's to keep the varying font sizes from effecting the overall menu's width.